# Proporties of linear-combinations of normally distributed variables.

Tags: normal-distribution, combinations

At my school, to pass an exam, you'll have to score at least 230 points.
The results are normally distributed with $\mu=200$ and $\sigma=20$.

If I were to consider 10 students who attends the exam, where they achieve $x_1, x_2,...,x_{10}$ points.

**a) Whats the probability that only one student gets the distinction mark?**

I know that I can use the $x_i's$ as a sample from the described population.
If the $x_1,x_2,...,x_{10}$ are normally distributed with $X_i\sim N(\mu=200,\sigma=20)$, right?

But all of the $x_i's$ share the same mean value and standarddeviation which implies that 
$\sum X_i\sim (10\cdot 200, 10\cdot 20^2)$ . What's the next step now? I tried to define $\bar{X}=\frac{1}n\sum X_i$ so $\bar{X}=\frac{1}{10} \sum X_i$

This leaves me with $\bar{X}\sim N(\mu,\frac{\sigma^{2}}{n})$ which equals $\bar{X}\sim N(200,40)$

This is where I'm stuck. If I want to find the probability of exactly one student getting the $≥230$ points, how should I continue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of passing is an independent bernoulli variable with probability
$$p_i = P(X_i \ge 230)$$
Thus the probability for *exactly one* out of $10$ is
$$\binom{10}1 (1-p)^9 p^1 = 10 (1-p)^9p$$

Comment: So if I apply a z-transformation of $X_i$, $p_i=1-P(Z≤1.5) = 0.0668 $

which makes $P(X=1)=\binom{10}{1}(1-0.0668)^{9}0.0668^{1}=10(1-0.0668)^{9}0.0668=0.3585$

Comment: @Kristian Yep. Looks alright.